# Windows phone Binding xaml to class

Tags: xaml, data-binding, binding, user-controls, windows-phone-8

I'm having problems binding an variable color, which i have defined in a class, such that it can fill an area for me.

```
<UserControl x:Name="Portugal" x:Class="MiddleAgeWar1.UserControl_Portugal"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:country="clr-namespace:MiddleAgeWar1.ViewModel"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="152" d:DesignWidth="88">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Path x:Name="Path" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{Binding color}" StrokeThickness="1.34983" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#D5000000" Data="F1 M 43.4622,0.674866C 43.4622,0.674866 42.2811,4.3869 42.1967,4.97748C 42.1124,5.56805 41.8593,5.56805 41.5218,6.07428C 41.1844,6.58038 41.5218,6.74921 41.0156,8.43646C 40.5094,10.1236 41.0156,9.44879 41.0156,10.883C 41.0156,12.3171 40.9313,12.1485 40.9313,12.1485L 42.028,14.7639C 42.028,14.7639 42.7873,17.7165 42.5342,19.1507C 42.2811,20.5849 41.8593,21.5974 41.2687,22.1035C 40.6782,22.6097 40.2563,23.7065 39.6658,24.0439C 39.0752,24.3813 38.7378,25.0562 37.3036,26.0687C 35.8694,27.081 36.713,27.8403 36.2912,28.8526C 35.8694,29.8649 36.1225,30.2868 35.8694,30.9617C 35.6163,31.6367 35.8694,34.252 35.8694,34.5894C 35.8694,34.9269 34.7727,38.0484 34.7727,38.0484C 34.7727,38.0484 34.5196,38.3858 33.001,40.6636C 31.4824,42.9415 32.3261,41.0855 31.145,41.9291C 29.9639,42.7728 29.7952,42.6041 28.6141,43.3633C 27.433,44.1226 28.1922,44.9662 28.0235,46.5692C 27.8548,48.1721 27.686,48.1721 27.686,49.0158C 27.686,49.8594 27.686,50.9561 27.686,52.3903C 27.686,53.8244 27.2642,54.3307 26.758,55.2587C 26.2519,56.1867 26.3362,55.9337 25.83,56.3555C 25.3238,56.7773 25.3238,56.6929 24.3115,57.1992C 23.2991,57.7053 23.6365,57.2835 23.2147,57.5366C 22.7929,57.7896 22.6242,58.2115 20.0089,61.3329C 17.3936,64.4544 19.1652,62.5141 18.659,63.4421C 18.1529,64.3701 18.406,64.0327 17.8998,65.045C 17.3936,66.0573 17.3936,66.1418 16.9718,66.9011C 16.5499,67.6602 16.5499,67.3228 15.5376,68.0821C 14.5252,68.8414 15.3688,68.6727 15.0314,69.1789C 14.6939,69.685 14.3565,69.6006 12.4161,71.0349C 10.4757,72.4691 11.8255,71.8785 11.0662,72.3847C 10.307,72.8908 10.307,72.8909 8.53531,73.5659C 6.76366,74.2407 6.84802,75.8437 6.84802,75.8437L 3.97963,78.2059C 2.79853,79.1339 3.64217,79.0495 3.30471,79.8931C 2.96726,80.7368 2.46107,82.7615 1.61742,83.6052C 0.773778,84.4488 1.53306,84.955 1.27997,85.5456C 1.02687,86.1362 0.183228,90.1013 1.02687,90.4387C 1.87052,90.7761 2.88289,90.6075 6.08874,90.3543C 9.29459,90.1013 6.84802,90.3543 9.04149,89.9326C 11.235,89.5107 10.5601,89.5107 11.6568,89.1733C 12.7535,88.8358 12.0786,89.1733 12.4161,89.342C 12.7535,89.5107 14.4408,91.7885 14.4408,92.5478C 14.4408,93.3071 14.4408,93.3914 14.1877,94.0663C 13.9346,94.7413 13.9346,94.7413 13.4284,95.1631C 12.9223,95.5849 12.2473,95.7537 11.4881,95.9224C 10.7288,96.091 9.9695,96.4285 8.61967,96.8504C 7.26985,97.2722 8.02912,97.1035 7.35421,97.3566C 6.67929,97.6097 7.10111,97.5253 4.73891,98.7908C 2.37671,100.056 4.73891,99.2126 4.73891,100.056C 4.73891,100.9 5.49819,100.9 6.00438,101.237C 6.51056,101.575 8.53531,101.912 10.3913,102.165C 12.2473,102.418 14.5252,102.587 14.5252,102.587L 15.875,103.768L 15.4532,106.89C 15.4532,108.493 15.4532,109.252 15.2845,111.445C 15.1157,113.639 14.947,112.373 14.4408,113.301C 13.9346,114.229 13.9346,114.483 13.091,116.254C 12.2473,118.026 12.7535,117.182 11.1506,119.46C 9.54769,121.738 10.307,121.569 10.0539,123.594C 9.80078,125.619 9.54768,124.353 8.19785,126.04C 6.84802,127.728 7.10111,127.559 6.34183,129.162C 5.58255,130.765 5.75128,129.921 4.48582,132.115C 3.22035,134.308 4.06399,133.043 3.64217,133.971C 3.22035,134.899 3.30471,135.996 3.22035,138.02L 3.97963,141.142C 4.82327,142.238 6.08874,143.166 8.70404,143.673C 11.3193,144.179 10.2226,144.601 11.6568,144.938C 13.091,145.276 13.5128,146.035 15.0314,146.71C 16.5499,147.385 16.2125,147.553 17.1405,147.722C 18.0685,147.891 18.9121,148.397 19.5871,148.482C 20.262,148.566 21.6962,148.903 22.5398,148.903C 23.3835,148.903 24.3115,148.819 24.3115,148.819L 28.9515,148.144L 31.2997,148.263C 31.2997,148.263 32.7128,148.179 33.2822,148.158C 33.8517,148.137 34.6532,148.137 36.0873,148.032C 37.5215,147.926 37.8801,147.926 38.6816,148.032C 39.483,148.137 41.8452,148.411 41.8452,148.411L 45.1354,148.924L 49.6958,151.635C 49.6958,151.635 49.4708,140.162 50.8207,130.713C 52.1705,121.264 46.9962,119.464 59.8196,106.866C 72.643,94.2674 73.7678,89.768 74.8927,87.0684C 76.0175,84.3687 75.7926,67.4958 76.0175,60.7466C 76.2425,53.9975 81.9441,38.369 83.2096,36.2598C 84.4751,34.1507 86.5842,28.0765 87.6809,19.1341C 88.7777,10.1916 66.5898,3.52667 65.24,2.7674C 63.8901,2.008 51.2355,3.18915 50.4762,2.34552C 49.7169,1.50189 43.5021,0.770813 43.4622,0.674866 Z " Margin="0,-0.001,-0.409,-0.309" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88"/>

</Grid>
```

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MiddleAgeWar1.ViewModel
{
    class Country
    {
        public SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
}
```

I wish to bind the SolidColorBrush color such that it fills my area.

Comment: if your UserControl_Portugal control has it's DataContext set to an instance of `Country` it should work. (eg: DataContext = new Country();)

Comment: @jonasN89 have you find any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rearrange your code and start using MVVM. 
You can easily get it to work through MVVM.

Go to Nuget and search for MVVM or Galsoft.

In Model you define what you want.
Then you can create your country as a View.
And then binding is easily done in ViewModel.

It will take some time to get into it. But when you do everything is easy from there!!

Comment: I've also found out this is the way forward, so i'm starting on a fresh and seeing if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

bind it to your grid like this..

```
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" Background="{Binding color}"/>
```

and also implement InotifyPropetyChanged on your class ..it is good to do that...you can do that like this..

in your class do this..

```
class Country:INotifyPropertyChanged
{


public Country()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = this;
}

private SolidColorBrush _color;

    public SolidColorBrush color
    {
        get
        {
            return _color;
        }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
           FirePropertyChanged("color");
        }

    }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there seems to be problems with the InitializeComponent and the DataContext. Is this because I'm missing some code or?

Comment: look @JonasN89 you can use binding only when variable are defined like properties..your color does not have any get (that will be called when you use color in binding in xaml) so you are not getting your color..the way i thought you is purely basic..so just read about basics of databinding then you will find out what i am telling you ..